# using a label as a condition in sql statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
protected void goto_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblevent.Text == Request.QueryString["name"]
        const string SQL = "SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = "I want this to be lblevent";
                     }
```

This lblevent is retrieved from an item selected in a listbox in another page using request.querystring. I want to use the lblevent in the where condition to prevent hardcoding. I know that I can simply type the event name, but since I have more than 1 event i cannot do so.. Please help. Thanks

Comment: It fills me with joy to know that no matter how far we think we've gone with developer training, SQL Injection will never go away. For the lulz.

Answer (score 4):

Use a parameterized query:

```
string EventName = Request.QueryString["name"];
string Sql = "SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = @EventName";
SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, connection);
Command.Parameters.Add("@EventName", EventName);
```

And, as a cautionary tale, **never format or append to a SQL query string directly**:

```
//Don't do this
string Sql = "SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = " + Request.QueryString["name"];
//Or this
string Sql = String.Format("SELECT SMS FROM Event WHERE EventName = {0}", Request.QueryString["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

basics of non sql injection suggest that matt's answer isnt the best idea. Please use something a little safer. 
I believe SQLParameter does automatic escaping.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx